# ERROR 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' after install npm i react-multi-select-component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

ERROR 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' after I install npm i react-multi-select-component.
How can I fix?

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/server/denormalize-page-path.js'
Require stack:

Comment: how did you solve it?